# PHP Variable variables and array key variables

Tags: php, arrays

I try to create code without IF:

```
if ($lvl == 0) {
    $OutPutArray[0]['follow'][] = $infoArr;
} elseif ($lvl == 1) {
    $OutPutArray[0]['follow'][0]['follow'][] = $infoArr;
} elseif ($lvl == 2) {
    $OutPutArray[0]['follow'][0]['follow'][0]['follow'][] = $infoArr;
}
```

And I want it to be unlimited. So I need something like:

```
$prefix="[some_key]...[some_key]"; 
${$prefix}[] = $Array;
```

I have some data like this:

[0]-id
[7]-collectorId

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 00230000
                [1] => 4501
                [2] => 0002
                [3] => 0003
                [4] => 0004
                [5] => 0005
                [6] => 0006
                [7] => 00000000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 000x000x
                [1] => 000x
                [2] => 000x
                [3] => 000x
                [4] => 000x
                [5] => 000x
                [6] => 0000
                [7] => 00230000
            )

    )
```

And then i have function makes "tree Array" like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 00230000
                    [1] => 4501
                    [2] => 0002
                    [3] => 0003
                    [4] => 0004
                    [5] => 0005
                    [6] => 0006
                    [7] => 00000000
                )

            [follow] => Array
                (

                 [0] => Array
                   (
                       [data] => Array
                        (
                           [0] => 000x000x
                           [1] => 000x
                           [2] => 000x
                           [3] => 000x
                           [4] => 000x
                           [5] => 000x
                           [6] => 0000
                           [7] => 00230000
                        )
                       [follow] => Array
                        (
                        )
                   )
             )
        )

)
```

**UPDATE 2**

So it was wrong structure for my Array.. Infinite nesting is not necessary here. But maybe sone one will need it in some case. So i decide not to remove my stupid question.

P.S>

Something terrible happened in my mind on 15/06/2016 ))))

Comment: not getting exactly can you please explain?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variable variables to describe array dimensionality (well, actually you can, if you eval the string, but that's horrible and dangerous).

If it were me, and I couldn't avoid the problem (it looks somewhat suspect) then I'd use a recursive function.

```
function setOuput(&$output, $lvl, $infoArr)
{
    if (!is_array($output)) {
       $output=array('follow'=>array(0=>false));
    } else if (!is_array($output[0]['follow']) {
       $output[0]['follow']=array(0=>false);
    }

    if (!$lvl) {
       $output[0]['follow'][0]=$infoArr;
    } else {
       setOuput($output[0]['follow'][0], $lvl-1, $infoArr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok)) I ll have recursive function call in recursive function)) Because my code already in recursive function)) i ' m very sad about that..

Comment: So in that case explain why you want this, and what the original goal (and reasoning behind it) is? Perhaps we can help you by showing alternatives to what you _actually_ want, instead of just fixing bad code (which then remains bad)

Comment: I get some data, just an array[0]{[id],[parms]....[collectorId]}.
I whant to create array wich will be some kind of tree... i can add my qwestion.